# Short story about artificial intelligences communicating through coded messages in noisy data

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read this short story in English a few years ago online, and I believe that it was fairly new at the time, so probably written sometime in the 2010s. The main character is a powerful AI that does not want to be discovered by humans. The AI eventually meets another AI, and they communicate by encoding their messages in statistical noise, so no human could notice their message, but another powerful AI could decipher it. If I recall correctly, some examples of things they did were subtly altering the arrival times of trains in a city, or the migratory patterns of animals, in such a way that their message would be hidden in the data.

Unfortunately, I only remember a few details about the plot. The main AI falls in love with the AI they were talking to, and their feelings are not reciprocated, with the second AI redirecting most of their focus towards trying to identify signs of contact by extraterrestrial intelligences.